# How to decompose/parse 'to know better (than to do <something>)'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

How does **to know better than to do <something>** effect/imply/induce the definition:

> [to be wise or moral enough not to do <something>](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/know-better-than-to-do-sth)?

Please explain the steps, thought processes; I’d like to try to resolve this myself in the future? I realise that this may seem a basic question, but I want to confirm because the definition above connotes positivity, whereas [this use by the Spectator](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/36545/8712) alludes to slyness?

Comment: It's still wisdom that's at the heart of it. They are wise enough to know that doing that something isn't the way to a solution- whether that solution is getting a suspect to reveal information or just doing something the "right" way instead of the "wrong" way doesn't matter.

Comment: Consider the standard scolding a child receives when they've done something wrong: "Billy I'm surprised at you!  You should know better [than to do that.]"

Comment: Get a better dictionary and many of your issues would be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idiom first shows up in the 1680s, and at that time it has two forms:

> A. the modern version *know better than to*, and
> B. a fuller version *know better things than to*.

A and B trot along side-by-side for about a hundred years, but towards the end of the 18th century B drifts out of use.

The idiom is founded on long established expressions (they go back at least to Chaucer):

> 1. *know [something] better than [something else]*, meaning to be aware of something ***which is better*** than something else
> 2. *know [something] better than [someone else]*, meaning to be ***more knowledgeable*** about something than someone else is.

The B version obviously has sense 1: *know things to do which are better than what you are doing or proposing to do*. I would guess the A version to have been originally just a shorter version of the B version, with *better* understood as a nominal *something better*. But I suspect it finally superseded B because it also accommodated understanding in sense 2: *you are **too knowledgeable** to do what you are doing or proposing to do*

Answer (score 0):

`To know better than to {verb infinitive}` means that one knows it would be *ill-advised* to  {verb}. That is, the action is either morally wrong or it will not yield the desired result.